# How to add a trainable hadamard product layer in keras?

Tags: keras

I am trying to introduce sparsity in the training samples. My data matrix has a size of (say) NxP and I want to pass it through a layer (keras layer) which has weights of size same as the input size. That is trainable weight matrix W has a shape of NxP. I want to do an hadamard product (element-wise multiplication) of Input matrix to this layer. W multiplied element-wise with input. How to get a trainable layer for W in this case ?

EDIT:
By the way, thank you so much for the quick reply. However, the hadamard product I want to do is between two matrices, one is the input, lets call it X and my X is shape of NxP. And I want my kernel in the hadamard layer to be the same size as X. So kernel should have a size of NxP too. And element wise multiplication of two matrices is achived by the call function.

But the current implementation gives the kernel size as P only. Also,I tried changing the shape of the kernel in the build as follows:

```
self.kernel = self.add_weight(name='kernel',
                                      shape=input_shape,
                                      initializer='uniform',
                                      trainable=True)
```

But it gives me the error below:

TypeError: Failed to convert object of type to Tensor. Contents: (None, 16). Consider casting elements to a supported type.

Here P is 16 and I will get my N during the runtime and N is similar to the number of training samples.

Thank you in advance for the help.

Answer (score 5):

Take the example of the [documentation](https://keras.io/layers/writing-your-own-keras-layers/) to create a layer, and in the `call` function just define it to be `x * self.kernel`.

This is my POC:

```
from keras import backend as K
from keras.engine.topology import Layer
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Activation
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(7)

class Hadamard(Layer):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Hadamard, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def build(self, input_shape):
        # Create a trainable weight variable for this layer.
        self.kernel = self.add_weight(name='kernel', 
                                      shape=(1,) + input_shape[1:],
                                      initializer='uniform',
                                      trainable=True)
        super(Hadamard, self).build(input_shape)  # Be sure to call this somewhere!

    def call(self, x):
        print(x.shape, self.kernel.shape)
        return x * self.kernel

    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        print(input_shape)
        return input_shape

N = 10
P = 64

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(128, input_shape=(N, P), activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(64))
model.add(Hadamard())
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dense(32))
model.add(Dense(1))

model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')

print(model.summary())

model.fit(np.ones((10, N, P)), np.ones((10, N, 1)))

print(model.predict(np.ones((20, N, P))))
```

If you need to use it as the first layer you should include the input shape parameter:

```
N = 10
P = 64

model = Sequential()
model.add(Hadamard(input_shape=(N, P)))

model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')

print(model.summary())
```

This results in:

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
hadamard_1 (Hadamard)       (None, 10, 64)            640       
=================================================================
Total params: 640
Trainable params: 640
Non-trainable params: 0
```

Comment: WOW!! That was some quick reply. Thank You so much.

Comment: Actually no, I have edited my question to include additional details

Comment: My POC should work on that case too, take a look at my weight definition, I used `shape=input_shape[1:]`

Comment: Updated proof of concept to unclude NxP and the fit function call

Comment: The number of weights are only 10 (P) where as I want trainable params as (NxP) = (64x10 = 640). After running the code above I get it as P only:

Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
hadamard_1 (Hadamard)        (None, 10)                10        
=================================================================
Total params: 10
Trainable params: 10

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand why this don't work for you, I edited my example to show you that you can use this layer anywhere in your network and it will do a trainable hadamard product with any input shape. Only if you use this as your first layer you need to set the parameter `input_shape=(N, P)`

Comment: I tried this but the weights are 'barely' changing even after several epochs. Any idea, why?