# Why is my Locally Connected layer consuming so much RAM?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, convolution

I'm using Keras/Tensorflow with the following model:

```
def local_model(input_size = (300,320,4)):
    inputs = Input(input_size)

    local = LocallyConnected2D (2, kernel_size=1, strides=1, padding='valid', kernel_initializer = 'zeros', use_bias=False, activation='linear')(inputs)


    model = Model(input = inputs, output = local)
```

For some reason building this model consumes a lot of memory (on the machine, not on the GPU) and takes a long time to complete.
All in all, the model produces 768000 trainable parameters. Why does it consume ~11GB RAM?

What I really wanted to achieve here is weighting on each input pixel. If there is an alternative solution, please share.
EDIT 1:
I located an alternative method here: [How to add a trainable hadamard product layer in keras?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46821845/how-to-add-a-trainable-hadamard-product-layer-in-keras)

Sincerely,
Elad

Comment: The Dense layer will have exactly the same number of parameters 2 * inputs. But you're right it doesn't work, the outputs will be summed. (You can just for checking use the Dense layer to count the parameters in the summary)